# Convert string into dates in pandas dataframe and handle bad values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with dates stored as strings. There is some bad data in there which is throwing an error when I attempt to convert them to dates.

Here's the data:

```
df['strDates']

0       19990510
1       20150303
2       20090908
3       19920200  <-- Bad Date
4       20030530
```

When I run,

```
df['lastSaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lastSaleDate'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

I get an error:

```
    /Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format)
    434 
    435     try:
--> 436         result, timezones = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors)
    437         if "%Z" in fmt or "%z" in fmt:
    438             return _return_parsed_timezone_results(result, timezones, tz, name)

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data '19920200' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just coerce and dropna to get rid of it.    `pd.to_datetime(df['lastSaleDate'],format='%Y%m%d',errors='coerce')`